# add the results of threads together

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a function that I call multiple times in a for loop, each time the function is called I take its result and add it to an integer so that by the end I can print the sum of all the function results.

this causes my program to take a long time to finish and I'm sure threading will solve this problem. I just need to create a thread in the for loop, give each thread the function, then sum the results.

the only problem is I have no idea how to do that, how do you add the results of multiple threads together?

here is the for loop

```
int paths(vector<vector<int>> grid) {
    int num = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < grid.size(); x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < grid[x].size(); y++) {
            num = followPath(grid, x, y, num, 0);
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

I want to call the followPath function

Comment: [*I'm sure threading will solve this problem.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Ci44G8j1F0)

Comment: The _example_ of `std::async` is literally a parallel sum:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

Answer (score 0):

Each thread, when it finishes, acquires a mutex, adds its value to the sum, then releases the mutex. The launching thread then waits for all threads to finish and then reads the sum.

Comment: isn't mutex used to activate and deactivate threads, how can I use that too get a return value from a function

Comment: @JacobWilson Mutex is used to prevent more than one thread from entering a critical section of code that cannot handle simultaneous accesses. In this case, it protects you from the many strange and terrible things that can happen if two or more threads try to access and update the sum at the same time. How you get the `sum` into and out of the function... that's up to you, but I'd pass in a reference.